# Is there a way to display decimal values in Bar Graph of Image Chart in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, bar-chart, image-charts

When I am inserting a decimal value in Bar of Bar Graph through Image Chart then it's showing the decimal value. Instead of showing a decimal value it's rounding off the value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.